# Need loop within the java class using TestNG

Tags: java, class, for-loop, methods, testng

I already wrote a for loop if I have one method, but what if I have multiple method in my TestNG scripts.

I was able to make it work if I put a variable within the public class, but I need this to run hostnum 2 through hostnum 50.  So I need a for loop within the class while using TESTNG so therefore can't use public static main.

here is my code please advise me what I can do.  I'm a noob :(

```
    package firsttestngpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test5 {

    WebDriver driver;

    //I NEED A FOR LOOP WITHIN THIS CLASS!!






    //THIS IS NOT WORKING
/*  for {

    }
    int hostnum = x;*/

    //THIS IS NOT WORKING
/*  for (int x = 1; x <= 2; x++){
        int hostnum = x;
    }*/

    //THIS IS WORKING BUT NO LOOP :(
    int hostnum = 2;

    @Test(priority = 1, enabled = true)
    public void method1() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, enabled = true)
    public void method2() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("host" + hostnum + "_CR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are referring to? : http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/04/10/running-junit-tests-repeatedly-without-loops/ Maybe mixed with a static variable and you're set?

Comment: @BrandonLing not exactly. I'm not running junit.  Running my webdriver as TestNG.  I will need this hostnum to be run multiple times.  Think of it as loadtesting and creating multiple users.  The code example above is not exactly what my script represent but I just need to get this for loop going within the class so I can use that host number within all my 11 test method (which is not showing in my sample code)

Comment: Okay, so what about this, and set hostnum to be a static variable, then increment it in the methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128289/testng-webdriver-how-can-i-run-same-test-case-multiple-times

Comment: @BrandonLing I have googled invocationcount and don't see it helping my case.  I have 10 Test methods and most have hostnum.  I will need all 10 Test method to be run for hostnum=1 then 2,3,4 and you so on.  Think of it as creating 100 users going through a signup process, but it includes 10 Test methods on TestNG so I can keep each methods on my TestNG reports.  Thank you for you input, if there is anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parameters from your testng.xml and pass them to your tests.

Your testng.xml:

```
<suite name="TestSuite">
    <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="host" value="host2_CR" />
        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test2 -->
    <test name="Test3">
        <parameter name="host" value="host3_CR" />
        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test3 -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <test name="Test50">
        <parameter name="host" value="host50_CR" />
        <classes>
            <class name="SampleTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test50 -->
</suite> <!-- TestSuite -->
```

Your class:

```
public class SampleTest {

  WebDriver driver;
  String host;

  @Parameters({"host"})
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest(String host) {
    this.host = host;
  }

  @Test(priority = 1, enabled = true)
  public void method1() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  }

  @Test(priority = 2, enabled = true)
  public void method2() throws Exception {
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(this.host);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you peetya but this is not exactly what i'm looking for.  This will basically do host 2, host 3, and host 4 for the test method 1, and do host 2, host 3, and host 4 for test method 2, and then host 2, host 3, host 4 for test method 3, and so on...  What i need is for to do host 2 to do method 1-10, then host 3 to do method 1-10, then host 4 to do method 1-10.  So basically a complete loop.

Comment: i tried your parameter code and I might be able to use this.  I found an issue though I can't get beforeTest to work.  I get this error.  (((org.testng.TestNGException: Method method2 requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the Test annotation.... Removed 23 stack frames))) so i comment that portion out and just moved the at Parameters above at Test for method 2 and it worked.  This isn't actually what I wanted.  I want to do it on one browsers same session.  Also what if I need to make a lot of users, I don't want to create 1000 <test> in xml.  Good stuff though!

Comment: Ah sorry I left a a parameter in method2. If you remove it, it will work. I edited the code too.
If you don't want to fill the xml with 100 <test>, you can create your xml programatically in runtime. For example you add only one parameter to your test (for example "100"), and it will create your xml with 100 <test> in runtime and you don't have to care about it. You can read more on this link: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: Thank you peetya that worked.  I will have to research this xml programmatically in runtime

Comment: can you take a look at this      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719855/running-testng-programmatically-need-loop-to-create-multiple-test-automatically