# Running TestNG programmatically need loop to create multiple tests automatically

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, for-loop, testng

I was wondering if someone can give me the right direction for this.  Not sure if I'm using Map or HashMap correctly for loop.  I know it works if I do one parameters but I like to do 1-100 host parameters when I create my XML programmatically.  Can you show me what I need to do for creating a loop so I can create multiple test with parameter with host value 1-100. My code is as below:

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class Test1 {

    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    private void testRunner(Map<String, String> testngParams) {
        TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
        XmlSuite suite = getXmlSuite();
        XmlTest test = getXmlTest(suite);
        test.setParameters(testngParams);
        List<XmlClass> classes = getXmlClasses();
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        List<XmlTest> tests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
        tests.add(test);
        suite.setTests(tests);
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
        suites.add(suite);
        testNG.setXmlSuites(suites);
        testNG.run();
    }

    private XmlSuite getXmlSuite() {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName("Test Suite");
        return suite;
    }

    private XmlTest getXmlTest(XmlSuite suite) {
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("test_with_firefox");
        return test;
    }

    private List<XmlClass> getXmlClasses() {
        List<XmlClass> classez = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
        classez.add(new XmlClass("firsttestngpackage.Test5"));
        return classez;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Test1 program = new Test1();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //Need THIS CONFIGURATION LOOP TO WORK
        //NEED HELP HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        for (int hostnum = 1; hostnum <= 100; hostnum++){
            params.put("host", hostnum);
        }

        //THIS CONFIGURATION WORKS, BUT NO LOOP
        //params.put("host", "10");
        program.testRunner(params);
    }
}
```

This is the Expected XML but 100 times

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="3" >
  <test name="1">
  <parameter name="host" value="1" />
    <classes>
       <class name="firsttestngpackage.Test5">
       </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="2">
  <parameter name="host" value="2" />
    <classes>
       <class name="firsttestngpackage.Test5">
       </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="3">
  <parameter name="host" value="3" />
    <classes>
       <class name="firsttestngpackage.Test5">
       </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
 </suite>
```

I am getting syntax error
 
-Syntax error, insert "Dimension" to complete ReferenceType

Comment: I´d suggest to use an Iterator for the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /**
     * Get the number of hosts (for example from the arguments, 
     * or from a file, or from System.getenv, etc...)
     */
    Integer numberOfHosts = this.getNumberOfHosts();

    // Creating a new Suite
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();

    for (Integer i = 1; i <= numberOfHosts; i++) {

      // Creating a new Test
      XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);

      // Set Test name
      test.setName("test-number-" + i);

      // New list for the parameters
      Map<String, String> testParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

      // Add parameter to the list
      testParams.put("host", String.valueOf(i));

      // Add parameters to test
      test.setParameters(testParams);

      // New list for the classes
      List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

      // Putting the classes to the list
      classes.add(new XmlClass("firsttestngpackage.Test5"));

      // Add classes to test
      test.setClasses(classes);

    }

    // New list for the Suites
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

    // Add suite to the list
    suites.add(suite);

    // Creating the xml
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.addListener(tla);
    tng.run();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your working code and the loop that in the working code you are using string "10" but in the loop you insert the integer but your hashmap is `HashMap<String, String>`