# TestNG: Set invocationCount globally

Tags: testng

I want all my tests (let's say 100 tests, 1 per class) in several packages to run 3 times. I can set

`@Test(invocationCount = SOME_CONSTANT)`

But that would still require a hundred changes. Is there a way to set an invocationCount (or other params) in a single abstract class without resorting to adding this to every `@Test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build an annotation transformer implementation such as this

```
public class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        int someNumber = 100;
        annotation.setInvocationCount(someNumber);
    }
}
```

You then wire in this listener either using the `<listener>` tag in the suite xml file (or) by creating the service loader file `META-INF/services/org.testng.ITestNGListener` and then adding an entry for `Transformer` into this file.

For more information on listeners you can take a look at [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) blog post of mine.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into this and get back soon