# How to create testng.xml with following requirements?

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

Run tests in three browsers (chrome, firefox and ie) parallely. Each browser should open 2 instances. In total, on triggering testng.xml , 6 browser instances should be opened.

```
<suite thread-count=3 parallel="tests">
 <test>
  for firefox
 </test>

 <test>
  for chrome
 </test>

 <test>
  for ie
 </test>
</suite>
```

Please help me!

Comment: and so far what have you tried?

Comment: i don't know what to try and did not find anything when i browse for it. I  just know what i have written in the post

Answer (score 0):

In your TestNG.xml file , add a parameter for specifying browser type.

```
 <test>
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox">
  <parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
  <parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
    </classes>
 </test>

 <test>
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome">
  <parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
  <parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
    </classes>
 </test>

 <test>
  <parameter name="browser" value="ie">
  <parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
  <parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

In your test class receive these parameters and create a webdriver according to the desired capabilities.

```
package com.parameterization;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestParameters {

    @Parameters({ "browser", "username", "password" })
    @Test
    public void testCaseOne(String browser,String username, String password) {
        System.out.println("browser passed as :- " + browser);
        createWebDriver(browser);
        loginToApplicationOne(username,password);   

    }

    @Parameters({ "browser", "username", "password" })
    @Test
    public void testCaseTwo(String browser, String username, String password) {
    createWebDriver(browser);
    loginToApplicationTwo(username,password);       
    }
}
```

As you have set **thread-count to 3** and your requirement is to launch 2 browser instances in each test block. You have to refactor your test classes in the above style so that each method block create its isolated driver instance. Thus a total of 6 browsers would be launched.

Comment: Thanks, My requirement is to run same tests in both the browser instances simultaneously. for example, in both instances of ff browser, same test case (test1) should be running

Comment: Copy the class tag <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" /> 2 times in the xml , change the parallel attribute to "classes"  and thread count to 6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to do this through xml just workarounds.

You can add the [invocationCount to the @Test annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128289/testng-webdriver-how-can-i-run-same-test-case-multiple-times) for the test you want to repeat. Refer to link for more details.

Also you could create a duplicate of the xml file and run them as parallel suites using [-suitethreadpoolsize](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites) as argument. Also pass in both the xml files as argument. Refer to link for doc.

Plus as suggested in the answers before, copying the tests multiple times in same xml.